# Xamarin Pulling text from a Label in a Data-template(Listview)

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, woocommerce

I want to get the Text from the Label id to query a new load when the Supplier is clicked

```
private async Task InitAsync()
        {


            RestAPI rest = new RestAPI("http://azipit.co.za/mica-market-app/wp-json/wc/v3/", "ck_0112f135e2fxxxxxxd621f919bc890", "cs_38ea21f4d63xxxxxxxxxx1868993b66065dcb0362fa");
            WCObject wc = new WCObject(rest);
            var products = await wc.Tag.GetAll();
            var p = await wc.Tag.GetAll(new Dictionary<string, string>() {

                    { "per_page", "80" } }); ;


            productsListView.ItemsSource = p;



        }

        async void retrieveid()
        {

        }



        async void SupplierClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {


            RestAPI rest = new RestAPI("http://azipit.co.za/mica-market-app/wp-json/wc/v3/", "ck_0112f135e2f9b32cc14xxxxxxxxxxxx919bc890", "cs_38ea21f4d63exxxxx01868993b66065dcb0362fa");
            WCObject wc = new WCObject(rest);
            var products = await wc.Product.GetAll();
            var p = await wc.Product.GetAll(new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                {"tag" , tagid },
                    { "per_page", "80" } }); ;

            productsListView.ItemsSource = p;


        }
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Ecombeta.Views.Suppliers"
             Title="Suppliers"
             BackgroundColor="#c4c3c0">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>

            <ListView x:Name="productsListView"
                      HasUnevenRows="True"                       
                  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                      SeparatorVisibility="None">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ViewCell.View>
                                <Frame HasShadow="True" Margin="8">
                                    <StackLayout>
                                        <Label x:Name="idlabel" Text="{Binding id}"></Label>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding name}" FontSize="Large"/>
                                        <Image Source="{Binding ProductImage.src}"/>
                                        <Button Text="See Products" 
                                            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                            Clicked="SupplierClicked" />

                                    </StackLayout>
                                </Frame>

                            </ViewCell.View>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

I have no idea how to get the Id fro the "Tag" Which is my suppliers in this case So that I can Query to load the products underneath it, So my logic was to try and use a x:Name and pull the Text from the label as its loading them correctly

Any Advice or possible workarounds for this?

Desired Outcome: Click on button at Supplier it loads every Product underneath that Tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `BindingContext` of the button will be a reference to the relevant item for that row

```
protected void SupplierClicked(object sender, EventArgs a)
{
  var btn = (Button)sender;
  var product = (Product)btn.BindingContext;

  // now you can reference any property of Product that you need
}
```

Comment: Is var product = (Product)? or is Produce intended, Because if it is Product I get 'object' does not contain a definition for 'bindingcontext'.?

Comment: Amazing Thank you! I'm getting Specified cast is not valid.', Am I thinking about this the wrong way

```c#
            var btn = (Button)sender;
            var product = (ProductTag)btn.BindingContext;


 var p = await wc.Product.GetAll(new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                {"tag" , product.id.ToString() },
                    { "per_page", "80" } }); ;
            
```
the tag is just the query I need to run to load the specifics, Marking because even this helps alot

Comment: you need to cast BindingContext to match the ItemsSource for your ListView.  If it is a List<X>, then BindingContext will be of type X.

Comment: I think i'm Following but then I'd need to cast binding to <Product> where I need the id From <ProductTag> if that makes sense? The Structure is File loads -> Suppliers(a.k.a Tags) -> then should be loading in the ID to get corresponding products,  Is it because im generating on the same page?

Comment: I have no idea how your data is structured so I can't say.  But your question was how to get "Text from the Label id" and the Label is bound to the property "Id".  Your product class does not have a Tag property?

Comment: Well my logic is simply to take the ID form the Label inside of the data template and just use that to fill the    {"tag", .id}, query, Because otherwise I have no idea how id get the ID from the ProductTag Class when i'm busy generating the Product Class, I'm using the .Net Woocommerce Wrapper so the structure is there's I can pull the Tag inside of "Product" but I need to associate the correct products to the supplier by using a Tag(or so the shop is setup) So how would I know what the Correct product tag is? Sorry if im not making sense this is making my brain loopy

Comment: "take the ID form the Label inside of the data template" - that is the "id" property of your item.  I don't have enough context to tell you if this approach is flawed or not, but that is how to do what you're asking.  This is really a separate problem than your original question.

Comment: I got it Working I set the Data-context on the button to {Binding id} then on your method  var product = (Product)btn.BindingContext; just removed the Class call because .binding was returning the correct ID Thanks again!